# How do I localise the language of my Wordpress plugin ReadMe.txt file?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, readme

When I generate a .pot file from my plugin's php, it seems to include a) any headers, b) any strings where I have used __('string','text-domain').

How do I localise my ReadMe.txt? It doesn't seem those strings are included in my .pot file.

I tried using the __() function in the ReadMe.txt file but the strings don't appear in the .pot . Am I supposed to just have a ReadMe.txt file for each language? How does wordpress know to select the right language?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use functions like '__('string','text-domain').' in txt files for localization because it's a PHP function.

Another approach, you can use the library for markdown localization

https://github.com/markdown-localization/mdlm-sh

Comment: Thanks! Does anyone know what the typical approach is for localising the ReadMe.txt file on wordpress plugins?